# Boost.Proto : Is it possible for Proto transforms to evaluate a mixture expression of matrix & vector?

Tags: c++, dsl, expression-templates, boost-proto

Now I am trying to teach g++ compiler linear algebra so that g++ can rewrite an expression such like `(matrix * vector)(index)` as the loop for evaluating the expression. Basically this is what I expect as a next article of [the last article](http://web.archive.org/web/20120630201353/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2011/01/expressive-c-expression-optimization/) in the series "[Expressive C++](http://web.archive.org/web/20120628021148/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/08/expressive-c-introduction/)". That last article explains about how to make an EDSL for adding vectors, so that I wrote another EDSL for multiplying a matrix by a vector.

But BOOST_PROTO_DEFINE_OPERATORS macro cannot be compiled when the name of the Proto domain for my own matrix and vector classes is passed as the first macro parameter.

So I'm wondering if it is possible for Proto transforms to evaluate a mixture expression of matrix and vector objects. There seems to be no such example code which can be compiled, and the sample code in ["Adapting Existing Types to Proto"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/proto/users_guide.html#boost_proto.users_guide.front_end.define_operators) in Proto users' guide 1.57.0 is incomplete although it is about how to adapt existing matrix and vector types to Proto.

I'm at a loss.. Could you please give me some advice or hints?

And here is my source code. I'd be very grateful if you would advice me about how to fix it :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/proto/proto.hpp>

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
namespace proto = boost::proto;

namespace LinAlg {
    class Vector;
    class Matrix;

    // Functor for lazy evaluation
    struct ElmOfMatVecMult;

    // The grammar for an expression like ( matrix * vector )(index)
    struct MatVecMultElmGrammar : proto::or_<
        proto::when< proto::multiplies< Matrix, Vector>,
                    proto::_make_function( ElmOfMatVecMult,
                                            proto::_left, proto::_right,
                                            proto::_state) >
    > {};

    // The grammar for a vector expression
    // ( Now I consider just one form : matrix * vector . )
    struct VecExprGrammar : proto::or_<
        proto::when< proto::function< MatVecMultElmGrammar, proto::_>,
                    MatVecMultElmGrammar( proto::_left, proto::_right) >,
        proto::multiplies< Matrix, Vector>
    > {};

    template<typename E> struct Expr;

    // The above grammar is associated with this domain.
    struct Domain
        : proto::domain<proto::generator<Expr>, VecExprGrammar>
    {};

    // A wrapper template for linear algebraic expressions
    // including matrices and vectors
    template<typename ExprType>
    struct Expr
        : proto::extends<ExprType, Expr<ExprType>, Domain>
    {
        explicit Expr(const ExprType& e)
            : proto::extends<ExprType, Expr<ExprType>, Domain>(e)
        {}
    };

    // Testing if data in an heap array can be a vector object
    class Vector {
        private:
            int sz;
            double* data;

    public:
        template <typename Sig> struct result;

        template <typename This, typename T>
        struct result< This(T) > { typedef double type; };

        typedef double result_type;

        explicit Vector(int sz_ = 1, double iniVal = 0.0) :
            sz( sz_), data( new double[sz] ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) data[i] = iniVal;
            std::cout << "Created" << std::endl;
        }
        Vector(const Vector& vec) :
            sz( vec.sz), data( new double[sz] ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) data[i] = vec.data[i];
            std::cout << "Copied! " << std::endl;
        }

        ~Vector() {
            delete [] data;
            std::cout << "Deleted" << std::endl;
        }

        // accessing to an element of this vector
        double& operator()(int i) { return data[i]; }
        const double& operator()(int i) const { return data[i]; }
    };


    // Testing if data in an heap array can be a matrix object
    class Matrix
    {
    private:
        int rowSz, colSz;
        double* data;
        double** m;

    public:
        template <typename Signature> struct result;

        template <typename This, typename T>
        struct result< This(T,T) > { typedef double type; };

        explicit Matrix(int rowSize = 1, int columnSize =1,
                    double iniVal = 0.0) :
            rowSz( rowSize), colSz(columnSize),
            data( new double[rowSz*colSz] ), m( new double*[rowSz])
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rowSz; i++) m[i] = data + i*colSz;
            for (int ri = 0; ri < rowSz; ri++)
                for (int ci = 0; ci < colSz; ci++) m[ri][ci] = iniVal;
            std::cout << "Created" << std::endl;
        }

        Matrix(const Matrix& mat) :
            rowSz( mat.rowSz), colSz( mat.colSz),
            data( new double[rowSz*colSz] ), m( new double*[rowSz])
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rowSz; i++) m[i] = data + i*colSz;
                for (int ri = 0; ri < rowSz; ri++)
                    for (int ci = 0; ci < colSz; ci++)
                        m[ri][ci] = mat.m[ri][ci];
                std::cout << "Copied! " << std::endl;
        }

        ~Matrix()
        {
            delete [] m;
            delete [] data;
            std::cout << "Deleted" << std::endl;
        }

        int rowSize() const { return rowSz; }
        int columnSize() const { return colSz; }

        // accesing to a vector element
        double& operator()(int ri, int ci) { return m[ri][ci]; }
        const double& operator()(int ri, int ci) const { return m[ri][ci]; }
    };

    // An expression like ( matrix * vector )(index) is transformed
    // into the loop for calculating the dot product between
    // the vector and matrix.
    struct ElmOfMatVecMult
    {
        double operator()( Matrix const& mat, Vector const& vec,
                        int index) const
        {
            double elm = 0.0;
            for (int ci =0;  ci < mat.columnSize(); ci++)
                elm += mat(index, ci) * vec(ci);
            return elm;
        }
    };

    // Define a trait for detecting linear algebraic terminals, to be used
    // by the BOOST_PROTO_DEFINE_OPERATORS macro below.
    template<typename> struct IsExpr  : mpl::false_ {};
    template<> struct IsExpr< Vector> : mpl::true_  {};
    template<> struct IsExpr< Matrix> : mpl::true_  {};

    // This defines all the overloads to make expressions involving
    // Vector and Matrix objects to build Proto's expression templates.
    BOOST_PROTO_DEFINE_OPERATORS(IsExpr, Domain)
}

int main()
{
    using namespace LinAlg;

    proto::_default<> trans;

    Matrix mat( 3, 3);
    Vector vec1(3);

    mat(0,0) = 1.00; mat(0,1) = 1.01; mat(0,2) = 1.02;
    mat(1,0) = 1.10; mat(1,1) = 1.11; mat(1,2) = 1.12;
    mat(2,0) = 1.20; mat(2,1) = 1.21; mat(2,2) = 1.22;

    vec1(0) = 1.0;
    vec1(1) = 2.0;
    vec1(2) = 3.0;

    proto::display_expr( ( mat * vec1)(2) );
    proto::display_expr( VecExprGrammar()( ( mat * vec1)(2) );
    double vecElm = trans( VecExprGrammar()( ( mat * vec1)(2) );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow confirmed that the answer to my question is 'yes'. The trick to have my source code work is to define an active grammar for replacing matrix * vector with a `MatVecMult` object and to define that `MatVecMult` as a `proto::callable` object for making a lazy evaluation functor, `LazyMatVecMult`. When this `LazyMatVecMult` instance is called with `operator()(int index)`, it calculates the dot product of the index'th row of the matrix and the vector.

( Sorry for answering to my question by myself. But I think that I'm not alone to stumble on this stone about how to make a Proto-based EDSL for vector and matrix expressions. )

This source code is confirmed to work with g++ 4.8.4 :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/proto/proto.hpp>

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
namespace proto = boost::proto;

namespace LinAlg {
    class Vector;
    class Matrix;


    // Callable transform object to make a proto exression
    // for lazily evaluationg a. multiplication
    struct MatVecMult;

    // The grammar for the multiplication of a matrix and a vector
    struct MatVecMultGrammar : proto::or_<
        proto::when<
            proto::multiplies< proto::terminal< Matrix> ,
                                proto::terminal< Vector> >,
            MatVecMult( proto::_value( proto::_left),
                        proto::_value( proto::_right) )
        >
    > {};

    // The grammar for a vector expression
    // ( Now I consider just one form : matrix * vector . )
    struct VecExprGrammar : proto::or_<
        proto::function< MatVecMultGrammar, proto::_>,
        MatVecMultGrammar
    > {};


    // A wrapper for a linear algebraic expression
    template<typename E> struct Expr;

    // The above grammar is associated with this domain.
    struct Domain
        : proto::domain<proto::generator<Expr>, VecExprGrammar>
    {};

    // A wrapper template for linear algebraic expressions
    // including matrices and vectors
    template<typename ExprType>
    struct Expr
        : proto::extends<ExprType, Expr<ExprType>, Domain>
    {
        /* typedef double result_type; */

        explicit Expr(const ExprType& e)
            : proto::extends<ExprType, Expr<ExprType>, Domain>(e)
        {}
    };


    // Testing if data in an heap array can be a vector object
    class Vector {
        private:
            int sz;
            double* data;

    public:
        explicit Vector(int sz_ = 1, double iniVal = 0.0) :
            sz( sz_), data( new double[sz] ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) data[i] = iniVal;
            std::cout << "Created" << std::endl;
        }
        Vector(const Vector& vec) :
            sz( vec.sz), data( new double[sz] ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) data[i] = vec.data[i];
            std::cout << "Copied! " << std::endl;
        }

        ~Vector() {
            delete [] data;
            std::cout << "Deleted" << std::endl;
        }

        // accessing to an element of this vector
        double& operator()(int i) { return data[i]; }
        const double& operator()(int i) const { return data[i]; }
    };


    // Testing if data in an heap array can be a matrix object
    class Matrix
    {
    private:
        int rowSz, colSz;
        double* data;
        double** m;

    public:

        explicit Matrix(int rowSize = 1, int columnSize =1,
                    double iniVal = 0.0) :
            rowSz( rowSize), colSz(columnSize),
            data( new double[rowSz*colSz] ), m( new double*[rowSz])
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rowSz; i++) m[i] = data + i*colSz;
            for (int ri = 0; ri < rowSz; ri++)
                for (int ci = 0; ci < colSz; ci++) m[ri][ci] = iniVal;
            std::cout << "Created" << std::endl;
        }

        Matrix(const Matrix& mat) :
            rowSz( mat.rowSz), colSz( mat.colSz),
            data( new double[rowSz*colSz] ), m( new double*[rowSz])
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rowSz; i++) m[i] = data + i*colSz;
                for (int ri = 0; ri < rowSz; ri++)
                    for (int ci = 0; ci < colSz; ci++)
                        m[ri][ci] = mat.m[ri][ci];
                std::cout << "Copied! " << std::endl;
        }

        ~Matrix()
        {
            delete [] m;
            delete [] data;
            std::cout << "Deleted" << std::endl;
        }

        int rowSize() const { return rowSz; }
        int columnSize() const { return colSz; }

        // accesing to a vector element
        double& operator()(int ri, int ci) { return m[ri][ci]; }
        const double& operator()(int ri, int ci) const { return m[ri][ci]; }

    };

    // Lazy function object for evaluating an element of
    // the resultant vector from the multiplication of
    // a matrix and vector objects.
    //
    // An expression like ( matrix * vector )(index) is transformed
    // into the loop for calculating the dot product between
    // the index'th row of the matrix and the vector.
    struct LazyMatVecMult
    {
        Matrix const& m;
        Vector const& v;
        int mColSz;

        typedef double result_type;
        // typedef mpl::int_<1> proto_arity;

        explicit LazyMatVecMult(Matrix const& mat, Vector const& vec) :
        m( mat), v( vec), mColSz(mat.rowSize()) {}

        LazyMatVecMult(LazyMatVecMult const& lazy) :
            m(lazy.m), v(lazy.v), mColSz(lazy.mColSz) {}

        result_type operator()(int index) const
        {
            result_type elm = 0.0;
            for (int ci =0;  ci < mColSz; ci++)
                elm += m(index, ci) * v(ci);
            return elm;
        }
    };

    // Callable transform object to make the lazy functor
    // a proto exression for lazily evaluationg the multiplication
    // of a matrix and a vector .
    struct MatVecMult : proto::callable
    {
        typedef proto::terminal< LazyMatVecMult >::type result_type;

        result_type
        operator()( Matrix const& mat, Vector const& vec) const
        {
            return proto::as_expr( LazyMatVecMult(mat, vec) );
        }
    };

    // Define a trait for detecting linear algebraic terminals, to be used
    // by the BOOST_PROTO_DEFINE_OPERATORS macro below.
    template<typename> struct IsExpr  : mpl::false_ {};
    template<> struct IsExpr< Vector> : mpl::true_  {};
    template<> struct IsExpr< Matrix> : mpl::true_  {};
    // template<> struct IsExpr< MatVecMult> : mpl::true_  {};
    template<> struct IsExpr< LazyMatVecMult> : mpl::true_  {};

    // This defines all the overloads to make expressions involving
    // Vector and Matrix objects to build Proto's expression templates.
    BOOST_PROTO_DEFINE_OPERATORS(IsExpr, Domain)
    // BOOST_PROTO_DEFINE_OPERATORS(IsExpr, proto::default_domain)


}



int main()
{
    using namespace LinAlg;

    proto::_default<> trans;

    Matrix mat( 3, 3);
    Vector vec1(3), vec2(3);

    mat(0,0) = 1.00; mat(0,1) = 1.01; mat(0,2) = 1.02;
    mat(1,0) = 1.10; mat(1,1) = 1.11; mat(1,2) = 1.12;
    mat(2,0) = 1.20; mat(2,1) = 1.21; mat(2,2) = 1.22;

    vec1(0) = 1.0;
    vec1(1) = 2.0;
    vec1(2) = 3.0;

    std::cout << " mat * vec1" << std::endl;
    proto::display_expr( mat * vec1 );
    std::cout << " MatVecMultGrammar()( mat * vec1) " << std::endl;
    proto::display_expr( MatVecMultGrammar()( mat * vec1) );

    std::cout << "( mat * vec1)(2)" << std::endl;
    proto::display_expr( ( mat * vec1)(2) );
    std::cout << "VecExprGrammar()( ( mat * vec1)(2) )" << std::endl;
    proto::display_expr( VecExprGrammar()( ( mat * vec1)(2) ) );
    double elm2 = trans( VecExprGrammar()( ( mat * vec1)(2) ) );

    std::cout << "( mat * vec1)(2) = " << elm2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```